# Find out what fonts are being sent to a printer

Tags: printing

I have an issue where two computers running XP and with identical print drivers have different behavior printing over parallel port to receipt printers. For one type of receipt, receipt printing is instant. For another kind printing is delayed by ten seconds on most machines but not on the other. This happens even if I swap out printers.

I believe the delay is because this computer has a different set of fonts installed. (It is used for graphic design.) The printers have built-in fonts, and if you do not use one of the built-in fonts the printer has to build up an image in memory rather than just spitting out its fonts. For a particular kind of receipt with special fonts on a particular computer the computer is sending a font which the receipt printer does not have built in.

My question is, is there a way to find out what fonts are being sent to the printer? This would let me narrow down what I need to modify in the Windows font folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a jet-direct and then packet-sniff the output to the printer.

Personally, I'd copy all the fonts (.ttf or whatever) from the working machine to the misbehaving machine.

Finally, check on your Wordpad settings.  A lot of "general" printing output done in the Windows shell is by default routed through Wordpad.